# How to implement multiple Silhouette Authenticators?

Tags: scala, playframework, jwt, playframework-2.5, silhouette

I used the [play-silhouette-seed](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed) as a template for my application. So in my project, I use a cookie based authenticator (`CookieAuthenticator`). This works absolutely fine, even for REST calls via JavaScript which is embedded in my Twirl template. However, now I want to make also REST calls programmatically in clients other than a browser. As a consequence, I would have to retrieve the `Set-Cookie: authenticator=...` element on each response and set it as part of my request. In my JavaScript snippet which is embedded in my Twirl template and rendered in the browser, this is no problem because I don't have to deal with that, but for other clients (server etc.) this causes headaches.

I want to implement now a `JWTAuthenticator` in addition to my `CookieAuthenticator`. Is this even supported, or do I have to switch completely to `JWTAuthenticator`? Furthermore, do I need separate actions, even though everything should be the same implementation except the authenticator?

Comment: I'm also exploring this possibility at the moment. Since one Env can only have one Authenticator, I believe you'll need 2 Env to host the 2 Authenticator. Therefore you'll need to separate your controller to use different Env.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Silhouette allows you to implement multiple [**authenticators**](https://www.silhouette.rocks/docs/authenticator). Here's how you can implement the **[`JWTAuthenticator`](https://www.silhouette.rocks/docs/authenticator#section-jwtauthenticator)** that provides its JWT authenticator service along with your **[`CookieAuthenticator`](https://www.silhouette.rocks/docs/authenticator#section-cookieauthenticator)**:

1. As Douglas Liu, already pointed out in the comment, you will need to create an additional **[environment](https://www.silhouette.rocks/docs/environment)** type. It should connect an `Identity` with the respective `Authenticator`.

For example:

```
trait CookieEnv extends Env {
  type I = Account
  type A = CookieAuthenticator
}

trait JWTEnv extends Env {
  type I = Account
  type A = JWTAuthenticator
}
```

2. Implement the JWT bindings in your Silhouette module. Please take a look at **[play-silhouette-angular-seed](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed/blob/3d2ee03ee2ff2cd7deff7e4f939ffb3aa752e600/app/modules/SilhouetteModule.scala)** for a full example.

For instance:

```
class SilhouetteModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {

  def configure() {
    bind[Silhouette[CookieEnv]].to[SilhouetteProvider[CookieEnv]]
    bind[Silhouette[JWTEnv]].to[SilhouetteProvider[JWTEnv]]
    // ...
    ()
  }

   @Provides
  def provideCookieEnvironment(
                                userService: AccountService,
                                authenticatorService: AuthenticatorService[CookieAuthenticator],
                                eventBus: EventBus): Environment[CookieEnv] = {

    Environment[CookieEnv](
      userService,
      authenticatorService,
      Seq(),
      eventBus
    )
  }

  @Provides
  def provideJWTEnvironment(
                             userService: AccountService,
                             authenticatorService: AuthenticatorService[JWTAuthenticator],
                             eventBus: EventBus): Environment[JWTEnv] = {

    Environment[JWTEnv](
      userService,
      authenticatorService,
      Seq(),
      eventBus
    )
  }

// ...

  @Provides
  def provideCookieAuthenticatorService(
                                         @Named("authenticator-cookie-signer") cookieSigner: CookieSigner,
                                         @Named("authenticator-crypter") crypter: Crypter,
                                         fingerprintGenerator: FingerprintGenerator,
                                         idGenerator: IDGenerator,
                                         configuration: Configuration,
                                         clock: Clock): AuthenticatorService[CookieAuthenticator] = {

    val config = configuration.underlying.as[CookieAuthenticatorSettings]("silhouette.authenticator")
    val encoder = new CrypterAuthenticatorEncoder(crypter)

    new CookieAuthenticatorService(config, None, cookieSigner, encoder, fingerprintGenerator, idGenerator, clock)
  }

  @Provides
  def provideJWTAuthenticatorService(
                                      @Named("authenticator-crypter") crypter: Crypter,
                                      idGenerator: IDGenerator,
                                      configuration: Configuration,
                                      clock: Clock): AuthenticatorService[JWTAuthenticator] = {

    val config = configuration.underlying.as[JWTAuthenticatorSettings]("silhouette.authenticator")
    val encoder = new CrypterAuthenticatorEncoder(crypter)

    new JWTAuthenticatorService(config, None, encoder, idGenerator, clock)
  }

// ...

}
```

3. Add the `JWTAuthenticator` [**configuration settings**](https://www.silhouette.rocks/docs/config-authenticators#section-jwtauthenticator) to your `silhouette.conf`:

For example:

```
authenticator.fieldName = "X-Auth-Token"
authenticator.requestParts = ["headers"]
authenticator.issuerClaim = "Your fancy app"
authenticator.authenticatorExpiry = 12 hours
authenticator.sharedSecret = "!!!changeme!!!"
```

4. Create a separate route for authentication via JWT:

For instance, in your `app.routes` file, add the following line:

```
# JWT Authentication
POST        /api/jwt/authenticate        controllers.auth.api.AuthController.authenticate
```

5. Finally, in your `AuthController`, add the corresponding `authenticate` method.

Example code (adapted from **[`SignInController.scala`](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed/blob/master/app/controllers/SignInController.scala)**):

```
implicit val dataReads = (
  (__ \ 'email).read[String] and
    (__ \ 'password).read[String] and
    (__ \ 'rememberMe).read[Boolean]
  ) (SignInForm.SignInData.apply _)

def authenticate = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  request.body.validate[SignInForm.SignInData].map { signInData =>
    credentialsProvider.authenticate(Credentials(signInData.email, signInData.password)).flatMap { loginInfo =>
      accountService.retrieve(loginInfo).flatMap {
        case Some(user) => silhouette.env.authenticatorService.create(loginInfo).map {
          case authenticator if signInData.rememberMe =>
            val c = configuration.underlying
            authenticator.copy(
              expirationDateTime = clock.now + c.as[FiniteDuration]("silhouette.authenticator.rememberMe.authenticatorExpiry"),
              idleTimeout = c.getAs[FiniteDuration]("silhouette.authenticator.rememberMe.authenticatorIdleTimeout")
            )
          case authenticator => authenticator
        }.flatMap { authenticator =>
          Logger.info(s"User ${user._id} successfully authenticated.")
          silhouette.env.eventBus.publish(LoginEvent(user, request))
          silhouette.env.authenticatorService.init(authenticator).map { token =>
            Ok(Json.obj("token" -> token))
          }
        }
        case None => Future.failed(new IdentityNotFoundException("Couldn't find user."))
      }
    }.recover {
      /* Login did not succeed, because user provided invalid credentials. */
      case e: ProviderException =>
        Logger.info(s"Host ${request.remoteAddress} tried to login with invalid credentials (email: ${signInData.email}).")
        Unauthorized(Json.obj("error" -> Messages("error.invalidCredentials")))
    }
  }.recoverTotal {
    case e: JsError =>
      Logger.info(s"Host ${request.remoteAddress} sent invalid auth payload. Error: $e.")
      Future.successful(Unauthorized(Json.obj("error" -> Messages("error.invalidPayload"))))
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great start but I fail to see why sillhouette's actions aren't used, to me it seems like it'd alleviate a great part of the work.

Comment: @Matthias - What is `authenticator` in `authenticator.fieldName = "X-Auth-Token"`. Is it some global configuration object exposed by `Silhouette`? I have noticed the use of `authenticator` in documentation but I couldn't get my head around where it comes from? Is it a single object which is used for all types of authenticators?

Comment: @ManuChadha It really doesn't matter how you name it. For instance, the first parameter of `CookieAuthenticatorService` expects an instance of type `CookieAuthenticatorSettings`, which is created in the method `provideCookieAuthenticatorService` located in the Silhouette module (see example provided as part of the answer).

Comment: @Matthias - I didn't know about the typesafe config library. So `silhouette.conf` is a file in which I define various properties (eg `authenticator.cookieName = "someName"`). The file is compatible with typesafe config library and the file (and properties) could be read by a `Configuration` object (`configuration.underlying.as[CookieAuthenticatorSettings]("silhouette.authenticator")`. If I have two different authenticators (say credential and JWT) then to specify their configuration I'll need to create two separate groups (eg `autheticatorCredential.cookieName` and `authenticatorJWT.fieldName`

Comment: @ManuChadha That should work yes, provided that the parameters match the respective `class` definition. However, you could also keep `authenticator` as a base for both authenticators if you like.